# How to check if my form array has the object already

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Reactive form, something like this:

```
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
       lastName: new FormControl(''),
       address: this.fb.group({
          input: new FormArray([])
      }),
  });
```

and I have one object, something like this:

```
obj = {
    teste1: 'teste1',
    teste2: 0,
    teste3: 1,
  };
```

I want this kind of response:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    address: [
      { id: teste1, value: 'teste1' },
      { id: teste2, value: 0 },
      { id: teste3, value: 'teste2' },
    ],
  });
```

So I have a method that has a obj as param, and I need to verify if the array has already the obj, only update the value, if not, create a new object.
so I tried:

```
  get addressArray() {
        return this.profileForm.get('address').get('input') as FormArray;
      }

    toDo(objParam) { //logic comes here
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if(true){
            this.addressArray?.get(key)?.setValue(value);
          } else {
            this.addressArray.push(this.fb.control({[key] : value});
          }
        });
      }
```

you can see the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gjgxgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: When you write `if(true){...}`, the `else{...}`-condition will never be reached.

Comment: this is the part of the coide that I don't know how to do haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused between you wanna update the **profileForm** and push into it's **addressArray**. Is this correct or if you want to update the current addressArray, too?

To check if the object exists you can use `this.profileForm.controls[key]`

```
toDo(objParam) {
    Object.entries(objParam).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (this.profileForm.controls[key]) {
        this.profileForm?.get(key)?.setValue(value);
      } else {
        this.addressArray.push(this.fb.control({ [key]: value }));
      }
    });   
  }
```

### UPDATE

This code will check if any object exists in addressArray.

```
  toDo(objParam) {
    console.log(this.addressArray)
    Object.entries(objParam).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      let found = false;
      for (let data of this.addressArray.controls) {
        if ((data as FormGroup).controls[key]) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (found) {
        this.addressArray.controls.find(f => (f as FormGroup).controls[key] as FormGroup).get(key).setValue(value)
      } else {
        this.addressArray.push(this.fb.group({[key]: this.fb.control( value )}));
      }
    });  
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, that part of the code was wrong.
I want to check if the array has the key. But my array is a array of object

Comment: Yes, I understand. I wanna update my post now.

Comment: Does it work? So you can rate up and/or set it to answer